# What does a period in the file permissions mean?

Tags: bash, file-permissions, ls

I found a permission character in the output of 'ls -l' which i don't understand:

```
[root@gnurr ~]# ls -l  /etc/cron.daily/
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  265 Sep 10 16:04 0logwatch
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  118 Aug 17 12:21 cups
```

There is a period after the standard permission characters  for the file 'cups', but it isn't there for the file '0logwatch'

I found many of these dots all over the place - they also appear for directories or soft links, but they seem never to show up for files i created myself.

I found some posts which mentioned a '@' or a '+' at this position meaning 'extended attributes' or 'extended security information', but nothing about '.'.

Does anybody know what the dot means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the info/man pages:

> GNU 'ls' uses a '.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
>   security context, but no other alternate access method.

The whole section also mentions a '+', which is relevant:

> Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
>   whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
>   applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode bits
>   is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is a
>   printing character, then there is such a method.
>
> GNU 'ls' uses a '.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
>   security context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
>   marked with a '+' character.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove SELinux security with:

```
setfattr -h -x security.selinux filename.ext
```